# How to convert PDF to make it to be two compacted pages on side when printing?

Tags: pdf, conversion, printing

I have: PDF document with a 800 pages book. If I just print it it will take 400 sheets of paper - too much.

I want: converted PDF document that have 400 pages: each page is two pages of original document. It can be printed on 200 double-sided steets: both more portable and cheaper.

[image: diagram that shoes what I want]

Comment: In Adobe Reader, the Print command has an option for [booklet printing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WSA2354511-30E7-4d18-9FB2-AC4A96EC533A.html): look in the "page scaling" drop down box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Web search turned up quite a few apps to convert PDFs to booklet format - for example:

http://opensource.marten.dk/sider/pdf-booklet-creator_67.aspx

Comment: "booklet" - thanks, now I know what to search for.

Comment: Looks like "ps2book" thing works.

Comment: If you have the program used to create the original PDF this may lay things out for you - I used to produce books, brochures and training manuals this way in Pagemaker and InDesign

Answer (score 1):

if your printer has a print 'x up' option built in, that's probably the best option. I used to use the trial version of [fineprint](http://fineprint.com/) (prints an ad underneath) to do the same thing when my printer didn't have that option, but this was a VERY long time a ago, and i'm not sure if there's still a trial version

Comment: I want to have the ready-made PDF that will be just printed (not by me). Now looking for various scripts and tools: mpage - fail (breaks text even in "no-op" mode), psbook/pstops - fail (misplaced pages), looking more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Print&Share](https://www.printandshare.info), you can set "Pages on 1 sheet" to 2 or 4 for example for the printer channel.
If you then click the "Pages on 1 sheet" label you have an option to put the pages in the correct order for booklet.

Also make sure you select the Duplex option ;-)

additional options you might be interested in to save resources:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcRaMr5iL6k&index=30&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b15edgSvHRo&index=8&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2

[image]