# How to make pdf in size A4 whith two A5 pages?

Tags: pdf

I have an A4 PDF file.

I would like to have on one A4 page there are two A5 pages.

How is possible to make PDF like that?

I know how to do it in print options, but I want to make file already like that, because I will not print it myself.

Comment: Can you be more clear? I don't understand your question. :)

Comment: I want two A5 pages on one A4 page. I can do it in print options (just with clicking two per page). But I need to save pdf file like that, because I will send file to someone else to print so he wont do any print options, he will just print normally. 

That's why I have to somehow make that two a5 pages are on one a4 page and then save that pdf file. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: One option is to convert the PDF to PostScript, use some tool to do this with PostScript such as psnup or psresize, then convert back to PDF. This is not guaranteed to work for all possible PDFs.

Comment: Another option is to print the PDF to file and use the *2 pages on 1* option in the printer driver.

Comment: Are you looking something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/284978/how-to-convert-pdf-to-make-it-to-be-two-compacted-pages-on-side-when-printing)?

Answer (score 1):

It will have to be a feature of the software/driver you use to generate the PDF. there are many, and yours may or may not be able to.

If you use your 'Print' command and have a virtual printer installed, the printer driver may have the option, similar to the option in paper printer drivers. If not, try another one, there are a hundred free ones out there.

If you use 'Save-As PDF' in MS Office, it doesn't have it. Nothing you can do about that.

You could use Adobe Acrobat, which probably allows to convert PDFs to that format (I can't check, I don't have it)

Comment: why downvoted? do you care to explain?

Comment: @Hannu This solution is neither software or driver nor OS specific. It doesn't even have anything to do with your printers driver, as the OS is simulating a virtual printer. It is built into Windows, MacOS as well as Linux.

Comment: @Hannu also if it were a feature which only works with specific software, why would that make the answer less valid?

Comment: No, Adobe cannot print, Adobe _creates PDFs_ in different ways. Then the print driver prints it. Adobe happens to be able to create PDFs that have two 'pages' placed onto one larger page; but many print drivers can print PDFs _or any other file_ that way. You need to understand the difference between the two parts.